ms teams bot scheduling (python)
I have been trying to make a bot that sends a message every day at a specific time of day. The message sending works great but I can't get the scheduling part to work.


!pip install pymsteams
!pip install schedule
import pymsteams
import os
import schedule
import time

def job():
    card = pymsteams.connectorcard(os.environ["MS_TEAMS_WEBHOOK_URL"])
    card.text("schedule test")
    assert card.send()
    return




webhook_url = os.environ["MS_TEAMS_WEBHOOK_URL"]
print("webhook: " + webhook_url)




schedule.every().day.at("12:07").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60) # wait one minute


I am using datalab to run the code bc the tutorial for the ms teams bot said maybe something wrong with that?
oh and I just noticed the time zones may be off? maybe because the time on the datalab computer is the on that is used? would need to know where there servers are for that right?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
